# Apply attribute to nested tag that is stored in a variable in a jQuery wrapper

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JavaScript variable that is in a jQuery wrapper.

```
var script1 = $("<label><input type='checkbox' value='script_"
                + scripts[i].id + "' id='pre_script_" + scripts[i].id
                + "'> " + scripts[i].name + "</label>);
```

I want to apply an attribute to the input tag. If I try simply

```
script1.attr('checked', true);
```

then the `<label>` tag gets the attribute. I also tried

```
$(script1 + " input").attr('checked', true);
```

but this doesn't work. Is there a way to apply this attribute to the input tag instead?

Comment: What exactly do you expect `script1 + ' input'` to do? `script1` would have been converted to a string. What did you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
script1.find("input").attr('checked', true);
```

Comment: `script1.find(...)` would be even better.